# How to get radlistview items if you use paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radlistview

I'm using radlistview in  my asp.net project . The problem that when I have to get all items of radlistview it return only items of the current page.

Example :

```
radlistview2.Items.ToList();
```

Output :
I got only 10 elements which are in the first page

My Question is :

How To get all items in radlistview ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadListView1_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ID") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadListView>
        <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="RadListView1"
            PageSize="2">
            <Fields>
                <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="FirstPrev"></telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField>
                <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric"></telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField>
                <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="NextLast"></telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField>
            </Fields>
        </telerik:RadDataPager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadListView1_NeedDataSource(object sender, RadListViewNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data1 = new[] {
           new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1",Customdate = DateTime.Now},
           new { ID = 2, Name = "Name_2",Customdate = DateTime.Now},
           new { ID = 3, Name = "Name_3",Customdate = DateTime.Now},
           new { ID = 4, Name = "Name_4",Customdate = DateTime.Now},
           new { ID = 5, Name = "Name_5",Customdate = DateTime.Now}
       };
    RadListView1.DataSource = data1;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = RadListView1.Items.Count();

    RadListView1.AllowPaging = false;
    RadListView1.Rebind();

    int j = RadListView1.Items.Count();
    //Access your count here

    RadListView1.AllowPaging = true;
    RadListView1.Rebind();

}
```