# Email RadListView control full datasource results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik

I have a paged RadListView which only displays 10 results at a time.  I would like to be able to email and / or print the full result set of this control, but am having difficulty doing so.

I am using the following code to send an email containing the listview results:

```
private void SendEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mySMTP.blah.blah.lcl", 25);

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("MyAddress@test.com");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailAddress);

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

            RadListViewMaster.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

            mail.Subject = "Test Email";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = sw.ToString();

            client.Send(mail);   
        }
    }
}
```

This code does send an email with the page contents, however, it only sends the first 10 results (the PageSize); none of the rest of the results on the following pages.

How can I modify this code to email the entire result set, instead of just the current paged results?  Is there a better way than using this code?  I'm up for anything.

The RadListView is populated via a LINQ to Entities query, in case that matters.  Is there perhaps a way to just email the query results instead of using this code to email the page?

Also, I would like to be able to print the results as well, but I am tackling one issue at a time.  If you have any suggestions for printing, I would love to hear them.

Comment: is your `SendEmail(string emailAddress` emailAddress a string of comma or semicolan semp values..? if not then you will need to pass a List<string> because MailMessage To in regards to email addresses is a collection..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: In this case, it is a single value.

Comment: I would suggest placing the value of this `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mySMTP.blah.blah.lcl", 25);` in a .config file then in your code assign `client.port and client.Host` also I have run into the same issue using RenderControl() method I did something similar with DataTable and rendered the code Excel file in my case, as an attachment if you need me to post the method as an example not as an answer for something to follow let me know I will be happy to do so..

Comment: Disable paging (AllowPaging=false), Rebind(). See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132355/how-to-get-radlistview-items-if-you-use-paging.