# How to get RadGridView items using paging in telerik?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm using RadGridView and RadDataPager in my wpf  project . The problem that when I have to get all items of GridView it return only items of the current page ( that are only 10 rows ) and it should returns all items that exist in all pages.

Example :

```
list = Gridview.Items.Cast<User>().ToList(); //
```

Output : I got only 10 elements which are in the first page

My Question is :

How To get all items in GridView ???

NB:

My question is duplicated [How to get radlistview items if you use paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132355/how-to-get-radlistview-items-if-you-use-paging) , but the OP asked for a solution for Asp.net not for WPF solution.

I have searched for the same property mentioned in the solution , but I didn't find it .

Comment: You get them from the `RadDataPager` itself. How do you set the `ItemsSource` of the `RadGridView`?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion or what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You get them from the `RadDataPager` itself.

So if you set the `ItemsSource` of your `RadGridView` to a `RadDataPager` like this:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=radDataPager}" />
<telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="radDataPager" 
                      Source="{Binding Items}" 
                      PageSize="5" />
```

You should either get the items from the `Source` property of the `RadDataPager` control or from the source property (`Items` in this case) that is bound to it:

```
list = radDataPager.Source.OfType<User>().ToList();
```